# Float left, text-align center OR display inline but break line?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a navigation in ONE UL

This single lists needs to be on two lines at a certain li

it needs to be visually centered.

Usually I'd put this in two separate ULs and use text align center on the LI but I can't get to the HTML.

I tried floating the lis left and using clear :left at the LI I wanted to break but text-align center no olonger works. I could put left margins on the first li and the li where I want the break to fake the text align but the website is liqued so the width would need to change.

It's almost like I need to use a display block - or break here but allow the next line to be inline with it.

I thought that maybe I could use generated content to and a BR on something but it needs to work in ie7 at least.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question or not. have you tried `display: inline-block;` If I have misread, could you perhaps post the code you currently have and I might be able to see the problem a bit better.

Comment: post your code for better understanding

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't very clear. I think I've actually worked it out. I tried to give the answer as well as clear up my question but I need to wait longer as I don't have enough points!! I'll post back later if anyone is interested. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked it out. Sorry that my question wasn't clear - I'll try and clarify and then show how I fixed it.

Say I have a list:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

I want that to display horizontally but over two lines - a bit like two uls with the lis set to display:inline. Like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

BUT I can't edit the HTML.

Fairly easy by floating all the list items left but adding a clear:left on item 4.

My problem was that the lis were also set to text-align:center and by floating left they aligned the left. I could have added margins to the 1st and 4th item but the layout is liqued so that wouldn't work.

In the end I kept all the lis as display:inline but added "white-space:pre" to item 3. This meant that Item 4 visually starts a new list underneath but both of the lists are still aligned centrally.

I then ran into another problem that the gap between these 2 lists was quite large - the size of a line break to large so I halfed the line height and it all worked nicely.

not checked IE6 but have checked ie<9 FF and chrome on PC. Need to check safari.

Hope that helps someone!